# É possível passar parâmetro para página HTML via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho a página **index.html** que tenho uma **listagem de dados** conforme abaixo:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush listDocsFIn">
   <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="financeiro.html">
      <div class="media-body">
         <input type="hidden" value="78657563">
         <h6 class=" mb-0">User1</h6>
      </div>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="financeiro.html">
      <div class="media-body">
         <input type="hidden" value="8765544">
         <h6 class=" mb-0">user2</h6>
      </div>
    </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

gostaria de ir para a página **financeiro.html** recuperando os dados do input  que está com a **ID** do **usuário**.

Não sei também se estou tratando esse **ID** de uma forma correta.

Não posso usar o `PHP` apenas JavaScript.

Desde já agradeço pela Ajuda!

Comment: Fazendo o método do form  ser GET, os parãmetros serão passados no URL. Aí você recupera em JS na página destino. Creio eu que já foi rspondido como recuperar aqui mesmo no SOpt, vale uma pesquisa...

Comment: Obrigado Bacco!